# Setup multiple Postgresql cluster IPs in kong pg_host

Tags: postgresql, kong, repmgr

I am setting the kong as API gateway and using Postgres as datastore, I want to setup kong with pg cluster where if one Postgres instance down it can restart by using another one. Unable to provide multiple ips to pg_host in kong.conf

`pg_hba = xx.xx.xx.xx , xx,xx,xx,xx`

**I am giving IPs comma separated at facing the error 
 could not retrieve current migrations: [postgres error] host or service not provided, or not known**

When I am giving multiple ips space separated it always try to connect with the first IP and ignore the second. Help!!!